# Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('file://') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null')

Tags: javascript, html, google-api, api-key

I am accessing Google API to run an example found [Here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples). I have placed the API key I generated for browser applications in Google API Console, and I can't get a simple request to the urlshortner API. The API has been enabled in the same console. I used Chrome's developer tool and it gives me the following error :

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('file://') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').

I did some research and it may be caused by Javascript origins set. But that's in the OAuth section of Credentials.

Here is my code, exactly like the sample. I replaced my APIKey with ***.

I am not running this `.html` file on server. It's saved on my machine and running it in browser.

My code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function appendResults(text) {
        var results = document.getElementById('results');
        results.appendChild(document.createElement('P'));
        results.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
      }

      function makeRequest() {
        var request = gapi.client.urlshortener.url.get({
          'shortUrl': 'http://goo.gl/fbsS'
        });
        request.then(function(response) {
          appendResults(response.result.longUrl);
        }, function(reason) {
          console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
        });
      }

      function init() {
        gapi.client.setApiKey('***');
        gapi.client.load('urlshortener', 'v1').then(makeRequest);
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="results"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just guessing, but you may need to run the file from a server.  There are some issues with `file://` URLs not allowing cross origin stuff the same way as an actual server.

Comment: But shouldn't Developer's console not provide any keys for browser applications?. From what I understand these API keys are for scripts that run from browsers only, correct?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your comment at all.  Browser applications are scripts that run from browsers.